# 3d object not rendered

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I have a WPF application that has a main window. In that I have a frame, the frame content is a page.

Now in page is 4 viewport3D that contain Viewport2DVisual3D and in that I have image element.

**Problem :** on some PCs my application runs well but on some PCs my application doesn't render viewport3d or it doesn't render the frame. Dunno but it doesn't show anything in main window.

The problem occurs on an Acer laptop [Model](http://www.acer.co.uk/ac/en/GB/content/model/LX.RAZ02.097).

Rendered :
[image: True Image]

Not Rendered :
[image]

EDIT:
This issue occurred again when I placed the frame in a grid. (I show this page in a frame, that frame is the main content of my window: when I place the frame in a grid it didn't show objects)
Seems This Occure on laptop with shared graphics

EDIT 2:

```
<Page x:Class="MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              Loaded="Page_Loaded_1"
        x:Name="myMainPage" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"  >

    <Page.Resources>

        <Style  TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="MenuItemsStyle">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>

                        <Viewport3D VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ClipToBounds="False">
                            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                                <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="myCam" FieldOfView="90" Position="{Binding ElementName=myMainWindow, Path=CameraHeight}" NearPlaneDistance="1" FarPlaneDistance="10"/>
                            </Viewport3D.Camera>

                            <ModelVisual3D>
                                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                                    <Model3DGroup>
                                        <DirectionalLight Color="#FFFFFFFF" Direction="0,0,-1"/>
                                    </Model3DGroup>
                                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                            </ModelVisual3D>

                            <Viewport2DVisual3D x:Name="V2d3d">

                                <Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>
                                    <Transform3DGroup>
                                        <RotateTransform3D >
                                            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                                <AxisAngleRotation3D Axis="0,1,0" Angle="0" x:Name="aar3D"/>
                                            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                        </RotateTransform3D>
                                    </Transform3DGroup>
                                </Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>

                                <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
                                    <DiffuseMaterial Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True" Brush="White"/>
                                </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
                                                              <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
                                    <MeshGeometry3D Positions="{Binding   ElementName=myMainWindow, Path=MeshPosions}"
                            TextureCoordinates="0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0" TriangleIndices="0 1 2 0 2 3"/>
                                </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
                                <Border Name="mainBorder" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <Border.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="Border">
                                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1.2"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Background" >
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent"/>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" >
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent"/>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                                                              </Style>
                                    </Border.Style>
                                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                      Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}">
                                        <ContentPresenter.Triggers>
                                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ContentPresenter.MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                              // Axis Animation
                                            </EventTrigger>
                                        </ContentPresenter.Triggers>
                                    </ContentPresenter>
                                </Border>
                            </Viewport2DVisual3D>
                        </Viewport3D>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ContentControl.MouseLeftButtonDown" >
                  //Axis Animation
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ContentControl.MouseEnter">
                   //ScaleAnimation
                               </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ContentControl.MouseLeave">
                   //ScaleAnimation
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </Page.Resources>

    <Page.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            //Load Object Scale And Fade In
        </EventTrigger>
    </Page.Triggers>

    <Grid Name="MainGrid">


                 <Canvas Name="MainCanvas" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
            <ContentControl Opacity="0" Name="MenuItem1" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemsStyle}" 
                            MouseDown="MenuItem1_MouseDown" Panel.ZIndex="1" >
                <Image Source="/IsargaranProject;component/Images/isargari.jpg"/>
                <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.7" ScaleY="0.7"  x:Name="MenuItem1ST"/>
                </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
            </ContentControl>
        </Canvas>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Only things I can come up with are the following: 1. The 3D acceleration settings on the laptop needs to be changed. 2. Viewport2DVisual3D is not installed on laptop.

Comment: What version of WPF are you using and can you provide some code so we can see how you're building up the view.

Comment: I Added Code . Im Using .net 4 . And how install Viewport2DVisual3D. what setting i must do ?

Comment: What i can suggest is, that might be because of disabled desktop composition (somewhat a linuxy term). If graphics card drivers or directx redistributables are not installed properly; Or laptop is being used with low performance settings: then as a result composition (a.k.a framebuffer functionality as a opengly term) might have been disabled.

Comment: Not familiar with .net, but I would suggest using only one viewport to render your four views in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using OPENGL or DirectX3D, then see that the laptop which is not rendering, will have some missing plugins like DirectX 3D wouldn't be installed or OpenGL you can try this two 3D Rendering tools for the same.. i had tried this in past i had made a Graph program it was having the same problem, but when i installed OPENGL &  DirectX3D it was working fine!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  When answering questions please consider posting links to reference material substantiating your answer.  For instance you might cite a Microsoft page that states that viewport3d relies on OpenGL and/or Direct3D.

Comment: Sorry..! on that time i was in hurry so i answer fast, so forgot to add a link, but next time i'm sure to add a link..! Thanks

Comment: seems you had this problem before so i vote it up but i will try it latter when i see that client again.